# Rsync - Changes dont seem to be carrying across

Tags: linux, bash, backup, rsync

I have a script which I run each night on my web server to copy all the contents from the live store to a back store. I'm currently testing but its doesn't to be working in the way I need it - basically I need a complete copy of the live store to the back up store so any changes in live are shown in the backup store. Whats not working is if someone makes a change in the backup store these should be over written with the live data?

It doesn't seem to be working - have I done something wrong with the rsync switches? Just so you know its abouts 300G of data being copied

Thanks

```
   #!/bin/bash

#Nightly RYSNC backup script


RSYNC=`which rsync`
SOURCE="/mnt/sdb1"
TARGET="/mnt/sdc1"
MAIL_ADDR="user@example.com"
OPTS="-vaz --exclude=/sdb1/lost+found --exclude=/sdb1/home/temp --exclude=/sdb1/temp/_tmp"

cat /dev/null > /tmp/rsync-errors.txt

nohup $RSYNC $OPTS $SOURCE $TARGET >> /var/log/rsync-raw-out.txt 2>> /tmp/rsync-errors.txt


if [ -s '/tmp/rsync-errors.txt' ]; then
   mail -s "Errors on $HOSTNAME" < /tmp/rsync-errors.txt $MAIL_ADDR
else
   echo "Successful, no errors reported." | mail -s "Nightly Report for $HOSTNAME" $MAIL_ADDR
fi
```

Comment: No one should make changes in the backup.

Comment: Unless you explicitly tell it to, `rsync` will default to not overwriting changes made on the destination end. You can certainly give it additional options, as mentioned in other answers/comments, to overwrite things and make it a proper mirror, but the best answer is for there never to be any changes it needs to overwrite...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
rsync -avz --delete
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into a program called "rbme"

http://sourceforge.net/projects/rbme/

Which makes a wrapper around rsync and creates a new "daily" backup by first hard linking in the LAST backup, then ryncing on top of it.  It /appears/ as though you have an archival full backup, but only taking the disk space for the actual changes.

It also has logging and email abilities built in.